# iPhone image not loading every time

Tags: html, css

I have an image on my website. This works fine on any other device besides iPhones and maybe iPads. When you load the site for the first time everything is fine, then any time you refresh the image will not load anymore. I have tried lots of debugging, but can't seem to figure it out.

```
<img <?php if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone')) { ?> style = "height: 80px;" <?php } ?> id = "info_image" src="images/info2.png" alt=""/>
```

is what I am currently using to try and figure out the issues with the iPhone, but it just won't load after the first time.

http://allinrs.com is the site the issue is located at.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could post the URL of your website. So it would be easier to reconstruct your problem.

Comment: Added url to my site.

Comment: By the image you mean this list in the page center?

Comment: Yes the background of the table in the middle of the page.

Comment: Hm, seems to work out for me. (also after refresh)  _iPhone 5S iOS 8.3 Browser: Safari_

Comment: It seems it may be iPhone 4/4S or the version of iOS that I have. But when I load the page on an emulator, and flick my height property on then off, it goes back to normal.